# Maximum number of edges in a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

What is the maximum number of edges a planar subgraph of $K_n$ can have? Is there a simple way to calculate this if not, are there some values of n for which this is easier to find out?

Comment: This must be well-known: The maximum is $3(n-2)$ for every $n>2$
(the maxima of $0,0,1$ for $n=0,1,2$ are clear).
The upper bound follows from Euler's relation $V-E+F=2$ upon setting
$V=n$ and using the inequality $E \geq \frac32 F$.
This inequality is sharp **iff** every face is a triangle.
So to $E=3n-6$ can be attained inductively: start from a triangle
for $n=3$, and then to get from $n$ to $n+1$ put a new vertex in
some triangle and connect it to the triangle's three vertices to
split the original triangle into three.

Comment: Yes it is well known, for example it is on the Wikipedia page Planar graph; voted to close. 

Comment: Oh, ok sorry guys. But just to clarify I never found it on wikipedia. SO then the answer is 3(n-2)???


Comment: No problem. Yes for n >= 3, it is 3(n-2); see in particular the subsections "maximal planar graphs" and "Eulers's formula" of the above mentioned page.

Comment: Since there is now also an answer in the techncial sense, we can also leave it open from my point of view (I already voted, but have no strong feelings regarding this).

Comment: I can delete this whole thing if you want to or not. I'm just happy I gut my answer and a comment from Noam Elkies who I allready knew about because he is well know in the math olympiad world. I can't see the close votes but if you want I'll gladly delete this.

Comment: Please don't worry! We have many questions here that are a lot worse. This one is quite alright in my opinion, just slightly too standard.  

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose the graph has $n$ vertices, $m$ edges, and $f$ faces. By Euler's formula we know that
$$n - m + f = 2$$
Now presume there are at least three vertices. Every face must be a triangle, otherwise you can increase the number of edges by dividing a face with an edge. Since every edge borders two faces, $2m=3f$. Therefore
$$n - m + \frac{2}{3}m = n - \frac{1}{3}m=2$$
or
$$m = 3n-6$$

This can be achieved by triangulating the inside and outside of an $n$-gon. There are $n$ edges that make the $n$-gon, $n-3$ that triangulate the inside, and $n-3$ that triangulate the outside.

Please delete. I didn't see Professor Elkies comment.

Comment: you mean delete the question or your answer?


Comment: I am sure Yosef meant the answer; but I do not it should be deleted.

Comment: "Every face must be a triangle" - this is not true for the outer face.

Answer (score 3):

**Proposition:** If $\Gamma(E,V)$, is a planar graph (no multigraph) then
$|E| \le 3 |V| - 6$.

**Proof:**
  Let us note that this does not work for a multigraph where more than one
    edge could be attached to the same two vertices. Imagine a figure (below)
of two vertices and 5 segments attached to the two vertices with no intersections
other that the ends of the segments. This figure 
    has $|E|=5$ and $|V|=2$, while the inequality $5 \le 0$ is false.
[image: A multigraph where $|E| \ge 3 | V | - 6$. Here $5 > 0$.}]

Of course $K_n$ is not a multigraph but it is good to be aware of counter-examples.

We first assume that the faces are all triangles and show the inequality 
    \begin{equation}
  2|E| \ge 3|F|   \quad \quad  (1)
\end{equation}
    For example for one face $|E|=3$ and
    $F=2$ so the equality $6=6$ is achieved. However for two faces
    (for example a rectangle with a diagonal) we have  $|E|=5$ and
    $|F|=3$, here the inequality $10 > 9$ is strict.
    We do this by induction over $|F|$ . Let us introduce a new face $|F|$ by
adding one more vertex and two more edges on the boundary of the graph (note that since all faces are triangular we can not add faces inside the graph). We need to show
    that $2| |E| +2| \ge 3| |F|+1|$. 
    \begin{equation}
  2 | |E| + 2| = 2 | E| + 4 \ge 3|F|  + 4 \ge 3|F| + 3 \ge 3| |F|+1|.
\end{equation}

Now we use Eulers equation $|V|-|E|+|F|=2$, from which $|F|=2+|E|-|V|$ and
    replacing $|F|$ in equation (1)
    \begin{equation}
  2|E| \ge 3 (2 + |E| - |V|)    
\end{equation}
    then
    \begin{equation}
  |E| \le 3|V| - 6.
\end{equation}

Now what happens if a face is not a triangle. We need to add edges until
    making it a triangle, use equation $|E'| \le 3|V'| -6$ which is valid
    for triangles then remove the edges and find that for the new graph
    $|E| \le 3|V| - 6$ is a valid inequality. After adding edges to make all faces 
    triangles we have $|E'| \le 3|V'| -6$ where $|E'|$ and $|V'|$ are the number of edges and
    vertices of the new triangulated graph. When we remove one edge 
    which is common to two triangular faces, we end up with a quadrilateral.
    The graph has one less edge without removing any vertex. In general,
    we remove edges but no vertices to go from the triangulated to the original
  graph, so $|E| < |E'|$ and $|V|= |V'|$. That is,
  \begin{equation}
  |E| < |E'| \le 3 | V'| - 6 = 3 |V| - 6,
  \end{equation}
  from which the proposition is shown.

Now, a $K_n$ graph has $n$ vertices so, $|E| \le 3n - 6$.
However the number of edges of $K_n$ can be exactly counted. Put the vertices
in a unit circle equally spaced. That is, on the $n$ complex roots of the
equation $z^n -1 = 0$. Each vertex can visit exactly $n-1$ other vertices, 
for a total of $n(n-1)$. But each edge was counted twice (from $v_i$ to $v_j$ and
from $v_j$ to $v_i$) so the exact maximum is $n(n-1)/2$.

It is interesting that this serves to show the inequality $3n-6 \le n(n-1)/2$. . Use gnuplot or any graph tool to illustrate this. Of course the only solution is for $n=3$, where we have a single triangle. After that the inequality is strict.